# How to add the nested properties of an object to a FormData object?

Tags: javascript, object, form-data

I am sending data via fetch to the server with `FormData()`, both JSON data and files. I receive a JSON object with the files, and I update with `FormData.append()` like this.

```
var data = {
    title: 'A title',
    img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
};

let formData = new FormData();
for (var key in data) {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
}
```

This works, but only in the first level of the JSON object. And I need to send arrays of data inside my object, which can have files (I will represent the files with `{...}`):

```
var data = {
        title: 'A title',
        img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        images: [
            { img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/', imgFile1: {...} },
            { img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/', imgFile2: {...}  },
            { img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/', imgFile3: {...}  },
            { img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/', imgFile4: {...}  },
        ],
    };
```

I wrote this function:

```
function iterateObject(object) {
    for (var key in object) {

        if (Array.isArray(object[key])) {
            object[key].map((item) => {
                iterateObject(item);
            });
        } else if (typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            iterateObject(object[key]);
        } else {
            formData.append(key, object[key]);
        }
    }
}
iterateObject(data);
```

But in the server I end up with:

```
{
    title: 'A title',
    img: [
        'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',
        'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',
        'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',
        'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',
        'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',
    ],
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    images: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]',
};
```

Does anyone know how to update this object properly, no matter the amount of nesting?

Comment: A FormData object stores key/value pairs representing form fields and their values (string or blob). So it is not suitable for passing JSON objects (the images property in your example). What is your desired result?

Comment: There is a logical error in your `iterateObject` function. The call to `formData.append(key, object[key]);` should be in an `else` after the `if` and the `else if`.

Comment: Thanks Jenny, I'll update it!

Comment: By the way, the desired result is to get a formData fill with the data. I suppose that a library like [object-to-formdata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata) will be convenient here.

Comment: Why not stringify it all to valid JSON, send it to the server under a single key, and then Parse the JSON on the server to recreate the desired object?  BTW: `Array.map()` returns an `Array`, so you need to catch it with a variable and pass that into the `FormData` Object.

Comment: Hi @BrianPeacock, because I'm using `FormData` and I'm uploading files, so I can't stringify the data (I think).

Comment: In your example you are not uploading any files. You have URLs.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question, because this is an important requirement!

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to use `JSON.stringify` and send the `data` Object as the string value of a single key...

```
  var data = {
    title: 'A title',
    img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    images: [
        { img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/' },
        { img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/' },
        { img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/' },
        { img: 'https://fakeimg.pl/500x500/' }
    ]
};

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("json_data", "'" + JSON.stringify(data) + "'");
```

... you can then identify your incoming information on the server with the `"json_data"` key and parse it upon arrival.

Comment: Hi @brianpeacock, is it possible to stringify the files?

Comment: @Nikita: What files?

Comment: Sorry, I'm uploading files, and I didn't mention that. Is an important requirement though…

Comment: @Nikita: I get that. But there are still no files anywhere in your example. You have URLs.

Comment: Yep, didn't added them to the example, didn't know how to represent them… Maybe with `imgFile: {}`?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file) for more on uploading files.

Comment: Thanks! I can upload files, is working nicely… the problem is that my object can have files at any level of nesting, and I would like to update all fields with them.

Comment: @Nikita: What is inside of `imgFile`? The `{}` indicates a JavaScript object.

Comment: I'm trying to represent the file I'm sending. I suppose it is an object, but I can't inspect it for some reason. Anyway, there is no way to stringify a file, so I can not include it in the example, right?

Comment: @Nikita: OK, so it is probably some sort of BLOB. That could be added to a FormData, but not as a nested property, because FormData only supports key/value pairs and no object constructs.